# Converting Public workspaces to Private workspaces in iManage

Tags: imanage, worksite-sdk

I am using iManage worksite 9 and there are multiple workspaces which has been created using workspace creation. Now, most of the workspaces are having `Public` access while others are `Private`. I need to convert that `Public` workspaces to `Private` workspace which I can do manually one by one but I want to do all at once. Is there any way or script which I can use for the conversion. Any suggestions?

**Thanks in Advance!**

iManage Worksite    :  9.0

iManage Filesite    :  9.0 update 6

Comment: Have you tried using the COM for this? You can write your own utility in C# using the iManage COM.

Comment: No I don't want to build my own utility since it will take good amount of time and also I tried with scripts from backend but then found out that its not a good way since every workspaces have associated metadata so that's why is a risky thing to do so else metadata will be lost completely.
Manually it is possible to do one by one which I am already aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's still relevant, but you could use a tool like 'Prosperoware Milan Helpdesk' which makes WorkSite administration much easier and lets you modify many workspaces at once.

Another solution would be to run a SQL query that updates the 'default security' attribute in either DOCMASTER or PROJECTS table (I don't remember which one exactly). You would have to update the LASTEDITED date for the indexer to pick up the change and reindex workspaces' contents.